# Changing a related lookup filter criteria of a managed field definition

Tags: administration

I'm looking to change the Filter Criteria of a Related Lookup Filter but I am unable to edit any fields due to the package being managed?

For context, I am using Accounting Seed on my sole Admin account. Is there something my mind is skipping over in order to change the filter? If not, I'd have to go up the tree to them

`(Customer: Accounting Type CONTAINS Customer, Customer and Vendor) AND (Customer: Accounting Active EQUALS True)`

I'd like to change to

`(Customer: Accounting Type CONTAINS Rental - Personal, Rental - Business ) AND (Customer: Accounting Active EQUALS True)`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

[image: Screenshot of a managed field in Salesforce]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change Lookup Field Filters that are part of a managed package. Only the vendor is able to make such changes. You can introduce new validation rules and other customization, however.